# CSS Is there a way to write style to class that contains class

Tags: css

Is there a way to write style for class **parent** that contains class **child** ? For example I want class **parent** which has **child**
This is what i have:

```
<div class  = "parent">
    <div class  = "child">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what I want it to be:

```
<div class  = "parent" width = "300px">
    <div class  = "child">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS should be something like this ?

```
.child .parent {
   width: 300px
}
```

Comment: So the selector would read ".parent that has .child as a child"? No, not possible.

Comment: You might be able to get this to work if you use jQuery. You could select the child div, and apply a css style to its parent. With pure CSS, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Not possible, you could use java script to get the desired effects however

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution. You select the child element, then apply the width to the parent element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').parent().width('200px');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
}
.child {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```